# Digital Signature error - Signature length not correct: got 344 but was expecting 256

Tags: java, certificate, digital-signature

I am developing a digital signature java class using the SHA1withRSA algorithm with a 256 bits certificate. But I am getting this error:

> Signature length not correct: got 344 but was expecting 256.

I am using the SunJSSE provider (that not implements the SHA256withRSA algorithm) because he uses the PKCS12 keystore type. And I need this, because this is a batch application.

Is the SAH1withRSA algorithm incompatible with 256 bits certificate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you can't possibly have a 256-bit RSA certificate, or key. 256-bit RSA wasn't secure when RSA was published in 1977 much less anytime close to now. That exception says it is looking for a 256 **byte** signature, which is 2048 bits, implying a key and certificate also of 2048 bits, which is currently (since 2015) the standard and widely used size for RSA.

Second, yes **SHA1withRSA technically works with a 2048-bit RSA key (and certificate)**, although it is less secure. SHA1 was originally rated for only 80-bit strength against collision, and has been broken (at significantly lower cost, about 63 bits) about a year ago -- see https://shattered.io -- making it insecure for signatures in many cases, and thus leading more and more systems, programs, and users to reject SHA1 signatures. For example, all Oracle Java packages from 8u144 up (roughly last summer) have java.security `jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms` configured by default to prohibit use of SHA1-signed certificates *in TLS* (including SSL, but SSL is also broken and prohibited by default). Java doesn't currently prohibit other uses of SHA1 signatures, but may be changed to. And lots and lots of things you might want to communicate or interoperate with, like browsers, webservers, email systems, repositories, etc, either have already prohibited SHA1 or probably will.

**But it isn't necessary.** You can use multiple providers in one program, and in particular you can use the KeyStore PKCS12 from SunJSSE while also using the Signature SHA256withRSA (or other SHA2+RSA variants) from SunRsaSign. In fact it's easiest to not specify the provider(s) at all and just let `KeyStore.getInstance()` and `Signature.getInstance()` (and the other JCA interface classes) find the correct provider automatically.

Finally, **your signature is probably base64-encoded:** ceil(256/3)*4=344. Take a look at the data and see if it consists of base64 characters, and if so which set. If it is base64, decode it to binary (i.e. `byte[]` in Java) and use that. In Java8+ just use [`java.util.Base64`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html) which supports both variants now common: the 'MIME' variant and the 'URL-safe' (primarily JSON) variant. In older Java you can use `javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` for MIME, or any number of third-party libraries with varying capabilities.

Comment: Thank you very much, dave_thompson_085! Yes, I made a mistake writing "256 bits", the correct is "256 bytes". And  your comments were very helpful. Thank you again!